# Set steering wheel angle using Gamepad API

Tags: javascript, gamepad, haptic-feedback, gamepad-api

Is it possible to set a specific angle for a Logitech G29 steering wheel using the HTML5 [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API)?

I assumed the `GamepadHapticActuator` could be used, but the only [GamepadHapticActuatorType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GamepadHapticActuator/type) is `vibration`.

Also, the possible `playEffect()` type argument values are only `dual-rumble` or `vibration`, I don't see any way to manually set a force-feedback motor angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [GamepadHapticActuator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GamepadHapticActuator) only supports rumble effects and doesn't support wheel actuators at all.

Logitech G29 uses the Human Interface Device (HID) protocol, so if you're using a Chromium-based browser you can control the wheel angle with [WebHID API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebHID_API). See [here](https://github.com/nondebug/g29-wheel-demo) for a demo.

Comment: I will try it, thanks, but holy s**t, did you just write all that demo? That looks insane. Where did you get all the constants from, like `const VENDOR_LOGITECH = 0x046d;` ?

Comment: Time to just tape the G29 to a real car steering wheel = self-driving car...

EDIT: This is a joke, please do not try this!!

Comment: I wrote it a while ago, I don't have the wheel set up anymore. `VENDOR_LOGITECH` is Logitech's USB vendor ID which is the same for all Logitech USB devices and is documented publicly by the USB Implementers' Forum, see usb.org/developers. The product IDs I probably got from the device itself, it uses different IDs depending on its current mode. I learned how to control the wheel haptics by inspecting the Linux open source driver hid-lg4ff.c

Comment: Thanks! What do the "clearSlot()" functions do? There are a lot of "magic numbers", I am slightly afraid of damaging the hardware.

Comment: Also, I can't see a button/function to set the angle (?)

Comment: I figured it out, check out my fork: https://github.com/Cristy94/g29-wheel-demo I can apply force to left or right in a loop until we reach the desired angle.